# getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null) giving Exception caused by permission denial while having permision

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-contentresolver

I want to read SMS using a content resolver. I've added permissions in the manifest file like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null); //line that gives exception
    cur.close();}
```

But it's giving an error:

```
02-22 02:55:36.429 18963-18963/inc.osi.imossis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: inc.osi.imossis, PID: 18963
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{inc.osi.imossis/inc.osi.imossis.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/inbox from pid=18963, uid=10059 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/inbox from pid=18963, uid=10059 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()
     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
     at inc.osi.imossis.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The complete manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="inc.osi.imossis">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: Show your entire manifest, please.

Comment: @Doug Done please check

Comment: What is your `targetSdkVersion`? What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @CommonsWare API 19 kitkat

Comment: @Irtza Shahan: try my suggestion n please let me know if it worked for you or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem after 2 days of Headbanging search for solution there is a bug in Emulator of API 23 if Any one Else faces this problem just run it on a different device or on emulator of api level 18 or 19 it'll work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning and re-building the project?

edit: Can you try checking and requesting the permission at run-time?

```
final private int REQUEST_READ_SMS_ID = 1;  // A constant needed for callback
int hasReadSMSPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
if (hasReadSMSPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.hasReadSMSPermission }, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
    return;
}`
```

Comment: Tried everything in my brain could think off but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the app and install again and try.
As manifest changes does not reflect on re-installations sometimes.

If I am not wrong, may be you have modifies the manifest file after installation.
Just try your luck, it may work.

Comment: Did not there was a bug in emulator of API level 23 in android studio